# Deleting individual messages on Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch

How do I delete individual text messages from my watch? I can delete them from my iPhone but I can't delete from my watch.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [user manual](https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1708/en_US/apple_watch_user_guide.pdf), deleting texts is an all-or-nothing action. It removes the whole conversation. There does not appear to be an option to remove a single text. (Similarly, you cannot delete one email out of a thread, only the whole thread.)

Answer (score -1):

On the text page (with multiple conversations) swipe to the left the conversation you wish to delete, then tap TRASH, and TRASH again.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The question is about to delete individual text messages, not conversations/threads.